# How to check if a python function uses a while loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, automated-tests, bytecode

```
def foo():
    while <condition>:
        do something

def bar():
    for i in range(5):
        do something
```

Suppose I have two functions defined above in a file name `test.py`. Is there a way in python to write a function with the following behavior?

```
import test

def uses_while(fn: Callable) -> bool:
    (what goes here?)

>>> uses_while(test.foo)
True
>>> uses_while(test.bar)
False
```

I essentially need to programatically check if a function makes use of a while loop, without inspecting the code by hand. I've thought of using pdb.getsourcelines(), but that doesn't work if there are comments or strings with the word 'while' inside. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm thinking that you could filter out any source lines that have any non-whitespace characters before the `for` or `while`, although the challenge would be how to deal with multi-line strings.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Can you give some context?

Comment: Yes it does, thank you! I searched quite long for while loops but it didn't occur to me to search for for loops.

Comment: @Chris_Rands, yup, it's because I'm building some tests to mark student submissions, they need to use a while loop as part of the criteria.

Comment: @HHC careful because they can add `while True: break` and use a for loop and it will pass your test.

Comment: @Adirio yup that's one consideration, I will be checking that for loops aren't used as well. If they still managed to pass the functional checks while not using both while and for loops, I'll give it to them

Comment: @HHC Do list-comprehensions get detected as for loops? Because you can hide for loops inside list-comprehensions too

Comment: The `ast` solution will let you filter for and against anything that's a valid Python construct.

Comment: @Adirio nope, they get classified as a `ast.ListComp` class. Also for this question in particular, there's no easy way to do it using a list comp, so no worries there.

Comment: @sabik yup, thanks to one of the quick commenters earlier!

Comment: Of course another question is whether automated marking of student submissions is a good thing overall; that would depend a lot on the context.

Comment: @sabik If the student can go to a revision where you mark it manually you get the best of both worlds

Comment: @sabik I agree, to some extent. But in a course with ~800 students and limited teaching manpower, anything other than automarking is not feasible.

Comment: BTW, @HHC, are you familiar with the `hypothesis` library? Could be a good way of generating test cases :-)

Comment: @sabik yes, we use hypothesis sometimes, but with simpler assignments generally a few unittests will do. If I'm not wrong hypothesis generates arbitrary tests, which might not always catch every single edge case, so the results are inconsistent when run.

Comment: Yeah, hypothesis generates arbitrary tests; it tends to be much better at catching edge cases than hand-written unit tests, though... On the other hand, you then find out that numpy can't take the average of two numbers and ruamel.yaml doesn't always round-trip dicts with ASCII-only strings, which can be a bit dispiriting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import ast
import inspect
from typing import Callable

def uses_while(fn: Callable) -> bool:
    nodes = ast.walk(ast.parse(inspect.getsource(fn)))
    return any(isinstance(node, ast.While) for node in nodes)
```

On Python 3.9+ you'll have to change it to `from collections.abc import Callable`.

Comment: Note that this will specifically parse the version of Python that's running; supporting multiple versions will be more challenging.

Comment: @sabik not necessary to support multiple functions for my use case, but I'm assuming that the for and while loop syntax would not have changed much across the 3.x versions, if at all

Comment: @HHC I think the problem is if they use something from 3.8 and you are running your marking software in 3.6 for example, `ast` package will probably fail when he gets to that part he doesn't understand

Comment: @Adirio the marking software runs the same version of python that the students use, so that's not a problem. We wouldn't use a lower version than the students are anyway, to keep issues like this away.

Answer (score -1):

I wrote a simple function that can check if the function given as parameter contains a while loop:

```
import inspect

def test_while(func):
  flag = False

  body = inspect.getsourcelines(func)
  string = ''.join(body[0]).replace(' ', '')
  splited = string.split('\n')
  
  for chain in splited:
    if len(chain) > 0 and chain[0] is not '#':
      if chain.startswith('while'):
        flag = True

  return flag
```

Comment: What if there is a line like `print("Please wait while calculating...")`?

Comment: I removed the indentation so i only have to check if the while statement is at the begining of the chain instead of simply check if the while statement is in the chain, i edit my answer

Comment: That can still be tricked with a multi-line string...

Comment: It is very difficult to do this using string parsing. Next challenge will be `"""This is a while loop"""` where there is a carriage return before `while`.

Comment: Yeah that's true ... hum hum, anyway i don't think this is the way to do this